# cannot see the character mesh in unreal engine

Tags: unreal, unreal-5

I was adding the AIModule in my project, but, after I've rebuilt the project after deleting the Saved, Intermediate and Binaries folder, I can't make the Mesh in the Enemy Character appear in the blueprint:
I don't know what went wrong,
I can see the character in other places like the skeletal meshes, but not in the blueprint and in the blueprint there is nothing in the details panel as well:
[image]
[image]